# Select all elements of arrays that are inside an array

Tags: javascript, html

I have two list with 3 items each one, i want to show an alert message when someone click on any item.

For all List1 items = 'List1 item clicked'
For all List2 items = 'List2 item clicked'

Since the actions is almost the same I want do this in just one code block(so if I need to add an extra list in the future, the code is easy to maintain).

This is my first attemp:

```js
var list1 = document.getElementsByClassName('list')[0].children;
var list2 = document.getElementsByClassName('list')[1].children;
var listArray = [list1, list2];

for(i = 0; i < listArray.length; i++){
  (function(){
    listArray[i][i].onclick = function(){
      alert("element clicked");
    }
  })();
}
```

```html
<ul class='list'>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class='list'>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
```

But strangely that code assign onclick event to only the first element of first array and only the second element of second array.

So my first problem is I dont know how exactly select all child of all arrays in 'listArray' to assing the onclick event to all of them.

And my second problem would be that I dont know how to do this in javascript without event listeners: "If the clicked element is a child of list1 show "message 1", but if the clicked element is a child of list2 then show "message2". I suposse I need a if condition to do this but I dont know how exactly implement it.

Something like this?

```
if(elementClicked = childOfParentA){
 Do this.
 }else if(elementClicked = childOfParentB){
   Do this.
 }"
```

Here is a [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/GhostOrder/pen/OWReLo) with cosmetics

Please avoid Jquery solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code will work for the first item in the first list and the second item in the second list (because you have `[i][i]`, and 0 is in `[0, 1]`).

Here is a possible fix:

```js
var list1 = document.getElementsByClassName('list')[0].children;
var list2 = document.getElementsByClassName('list')[1].children;
var listArray = [list1, list2];

for(i = 0; i < listArray.length; i++){
  (function(){
    for (j = 0; j < listArray[i].length; j++) {
      var l = i + 1;
      listArray[i][j].onclick = function(){
        alert("List " + l +" element clicked " + this.innerHTML);
      }
    }
  })();
}
```

```html
<ul class='list'>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class='list'>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
```

> Note the usage of the local variable `l` to save the current list we work on in order to alert the relevant list.

Comment: what's the point of wrapping the second `for` loop in an anonymous function?

Comment: @SeanKendle I only changed a bit the original code by the OP

Comment: Derp, didn't notice that, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @SeanKendle you are welcome :) a voteup will also be appreciated!

Comment: you got it, dude!

Answer (score 2):

More precise way without storing in separate arrays.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("ul").forEach(function(ul, index){
  ul.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(function(li){
    li.onclick = function(){
      alert("elements of UL-" + index+1 + " clicked");
    }    
  })
})
```

```html
<ul class='list'>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class='list'>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that only the first/first and second/second ... etc respond to the click. This is because you specify it like that:

```
listArray[i][i]
```

Notice that `i` and `i` are always the same in that line...

You can do this a lot simpler if you would select all the clickable elements in one iterable with an appropriate selector:

```js
function handler(){
    alert("element clicked " + this.textContent);
} 
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.list>li'), li => li.onclick = handler);
```

```html
<ul class='list'>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class='list'>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

.className

```js
window.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  console.log (e.target.parentElement.className);
});
```

```html
<ul class='list1'>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class='list2'>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
```